# Execution level start app on second start doesn't call main method from code

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j to create an installer for my java application.
I'm using executable level "As invoker" and in the first start after installation, the application works fine calls all my loggers from the main class and all other classes. On the second start, an application doesn't call my main class. If I use the executable level "Administrator" application works fine. 
Can somebody explain to me how to fix this?

Comment: You can pass `/create-i4j-log` as an argument on the command line to get a log file of the native launcher.

Comment: I added `/create-i4j-log` and different between logs for the first and second start is this on the bottom of the file 
First time: `[140:977] calling main
[185:969] main returned
[186:4] dest JVM`

Second time:` [49:45] calling main`.

Like can't return main class?

Comment: "main returned" is printed if the main method returns. It seems that the main method does not return in the second case. You could add your own logging to check if the main method is called.

Comment: I'm using loggers in my main method but I can't see that loggers at the second start of the app.

Comment: Also when I start the app as Admin everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry, that seems like a very specific problem to your application, please send a test case to support@ej-technologies.com